# Behaviour of the crystal momentum under an externally applied electric field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals

Is there any equation which describes the behavior of the crystal momentum under the action of an externally applied electric field?

Comment: How would the crystal momentum (and you had better be careful about just what you mean by that) couple to an external electric field?

Answer (score 0):

Well, absent anything else, Bloch oscillations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_oscillations.